# python OrderedDict two keys and multiple values -> write to csv to import into excel

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

In Python how do I write below object to a csv file which I can later manually import into Excel?

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv

data = OrderedDict([(('2016-11-01', 'USD'), ['ECB News', 'FED News']),
                    (('2016-11-02', 'EUR'), ['Brexit News']),
                    (('2016-11-03', 'USD'), ['Yellen Speaking'])])

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    for each in data:
        for key, value in each.iteritems(): #<<<<<----- error here
            writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Error:

```
  for key, value in each.iteritems():
    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

CSV output wanted:

```
2016-11-01;USD;ECB News,FED News
2016-11-02;EUR;Brexit News
2016-11-03;USD;Yellen Speaking
```

Comment: `iteritems()` is a method on dictionaries not tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each` is the key in the `data` dictionary, which it correctly says is a tuple. You've probably just got the `iteritems()` in the wrong place:

```
from io import StringIO
with StringIO() as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter=';')
    for k, v in data.iteritems():
        writer.writerow(list(k)+[','.join(v)])
    print(output.getvalue())
```

Output:

```
2016-11-01;USD;ECB News,FED News
2016-11-02;EUR;Brexit News
2016-11-03;USD;Yellen Speaking
```

You could replace:

```
    for k, v in data.iteritems():
        writer.writerow(list(k)+[','.join(v)])
```

with:

```
    writer.writerows(list(k)+[','.join(v)] for k, v in data.iteritems())
```

Comment: Thank you AChampion, it worked. Also I need to change the iteration code to ->>>>  for k, v in data.items():

Comment: @KS if you are using python3 then yes, use `data.items()`. In python2, `.iteritems()` returns an iterator and is less expensive than `.items()` which returns a `list`.

Comment: @AC thanks for that info, that clarifies why it was not working.